# Finding number of entires in MySQL by month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the number of entires in MySQL by month:

here is my code:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y') `mmyy`, 
       SUM(class IN ('local')) and (status IN ('Open', 'Closed', 'Confirmed')) `fulfilledlocal`,
       SUM(class IN ('local')) and (status IN ('Canceled', 'Unconfirmed', 'Communicating')) `unfulfilledlocal`,
       SUM(class IN ('local')) `alllocal`
FROM `reservations`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y'), YEAR(bookingdatetime)
ORDER BY YEAR(bookingdatetime), DATE_FORMAT(bookingdatetime, '%m/%y')
```

The alllocal result works correctly but when I try to get the fulfilledlocal and unfulfilledlocal it gives me only the first, not all three.

Edit:

I have three columns in my `reservations` table;

```
+-----------------+------------------+-------+
| bookingdatetime |    status        | class |
+-----------------+------------------+-------+
|                 | *possible values |       |
|                 | Open             |       |
|                 | Closed           |       |
|                 | Confirmed        |       |
|                 | Canceled         |       |
|                 | Unconfirmed      |       |
|                 | Communicating    |       |
+-----------------+------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Please include example data from `reservations` tables

Comment: I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: There are `[share  edit] ` links in grey below the question

Comment: Check update...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the `AND` condition inside the argument to `SUM()`.

```
SUM(class IN ('local') and status IN ('Open', 'Closed', 'Confirmed')) `fulfilledlocal`,
SUM(class IN ('local') and status IN ('Canceled', 'Unconfirmed', 'Communicating')) `unfulfilledlocal`,
```